# Are 2 passports valid when one is British and the other applied for in Bulgaria

Tags: passports, uk-citizens, bulgarian-citizens

My daughter who is 4 was born in the UK and holds a British Passport.
Her mother who is Bulgarian wants her to have a passport from Bulgaria. Question is will she be able to retain the British passport if she has a second passport.

Comment: This is kinda off topic since, as it stands, the question has more to do about citizenship than travel.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your daughter will be able to retain both her passport and her British citizenship.

> Dual citizenship (also known as dual nationality) is allowed in the
>   UK. This means you can be a British citizen and also a citizen of
>   other countries.

Source:  [Dual Citizenship](https://www.gov.uk/dual-citizenship)

> Bulgaria allows its citizens to hold foreign citizenship in addition
>   to their Bulgarian citizenship. Some countries, however, do not permit
>   multiple citizenship e.g. adults who acquired Bulgarian and Japanese
>   citizenship by birth must declare, to the latter's Ministry of
>   Justice, before turning 22, which citizenship they want to keep.

Source: [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_nationality_law#Dual_citizenship)

Unlike some other countries, the UK places no restrictions on the number of nationalities a person can claim.  There are an [estimated 500,000](http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/rel/migration1/population-by-country-of-birth-and-nationality/2012/population-by-country-of-birth-and-nationality-report.html) dual or treble nationals inside the London Orbital alone (my own family, for example, is treble).

She can also use her [Bulgarian passport to come and go from the UK](http://www.euromove.org.uk/index.php?id=20539), but the rules on that are more complex.

**Adding...**

The controlling *legal* reference is the [British Nationality Act 1981](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61)